# Visual Studio 2013 VB Program Not Showing Image

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio-2013

I have designed a calculator-like app using [mahapps](http://mahapps.com/) metro in VB.  It works perfectly.  I added both a .jpg and .png image to my Resources file, and add it within my xaml file, and it shows perfectly.  Though when I press the "Start" button to test my program – it doesn't show the image in the app. I've read on here that if I change the build state to Resources, then it should appear.  Though when I do that, I get some permission access error.  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the [so]. Please rephrase your question, focusing on that "permissions access error" – please provide sufficient related details to that error. And also try to search for that problem, too, maybe you will find Q&A addressing the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I apologize for not being more clear.

When I compile the app, the image does not show (it is in resources).  The build action is currently set to Page.  When I change it to Resources (as I searched for this on here and was recommended), I get the permission error:

Error 1 'inputModuleFam' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: It looks that your problem is specific to [tag:mahapps.metro]. To confirm, please build *standard* WPF application with image – will the image be there during the runtime*?    Also please improve your question in way that you [edit] it and put all necessary facts including the error message and answer to the above question (*) inside it. This will help other users to see all the facts you collected in one place. [so] is driven by good questions – see [ask].

Comment: I created a new project, added the image to the Resources, added the Image tag to the xaml file, and compiled the program.  It still didn't show -- whether I compiled as "Page" or "Resources".  In this case, there was no error message.

Comment: Yes exactly. My colleague has this issue, too – not resolved yet.  So you actually have *two separate* problems: (1) error message from mahapps and (2) Why image is not showing in *any* WPF application I build. I don't think they are related.  I would advise to [edit] the question, **remove** everything mentioning the image (also in title) and asking only for help with error.  And aside from that, do research about that image+WPF. There should be no problem with changing of question merit, because the question has no answers yet.

Comment: I fixed it with uninstalling Visual Studio 2013, and installing it again.  Likewise, in Resources folder -- I found my image, and set that build action to Resources, and it showed up on the debug/release build.  I left the MainWindow.xaml to Page as a build action.

Answer (score 0):

[The original poster said:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597809/visual-studio-2013-vb-program-not-showing-image?noredirect=1#comment53239943_32597809)

I fixed it with uninstalling Visual Studio 2013, and installing it again. Likewise, in Resources folder -- I found my image, and set that build action to Resources, and it showed up on the debug/release build. I left the MainWindow.xaml to Page as a build action.